# set focus to a div when any of it's content elements are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the following to set focus to a div when it is clicked or tabbed into.

It only works when I click the padding area inside the div.

Clicking on any of the child elements does not activate the div:focus.

Please how can I fix this?

**CSS**

```
.sidebar-message:link {
}

.sidebar-message:visited {
}

.sidebar-message:hover {
    background-color: lightyellow !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
}

.sidebar-message:focus {
    background-color: khaki !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar-message" tabindex="-1">
     <a href="#" id="pending_{{id}}" data-id="{{id}}">
     <div class="pull-left text-center">
         <img alt="image" class="img-circle message-avatar" src="media/profile-pics/{{uid}}.jpg">
     </div>
     <div class="media-body">
          <strong>{{{contact_name}}}</strong>
          <span class="badge {{color}} pull-right{{hidden}}">{{unread}}</span>
          <br>
          <small class="text-muted">{{formatDate last_seen 'dddd, MMMM Do h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
          <small class="pull-right">{{agent_name}}</small>
     </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

**some notes:**

1) there are multiple `.sidebar-message` rows (DIVs), and only one should be highlighted at a time

2) the list of `.sidebar-message` DIVs is not available @ DocumentReady, it becomes available when a XHR request returns data to be populated into a template via handlebars. One of the comments suggested late-binding to get round this

Comment: I doubt you can do that using pure CSS. But it is easy with Javascript.

Comment: @J.Joe at this point i'll take any solution that works.... :)

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle or codepen ....i just created one but couldn't replicate the issue-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKGwzG

Comment: Do you use jquery?

Comment: jquery is one of the tags in his question.  You could try the .focus() in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add a new class to the container when any of the childs get the focus.

Note: The added class gets not removed in this example once it is set. if you want to remove the `focused` class if the user clicks somewhere else, I suggest you implement a handler for `focusout()` accordingly.

Another note: I would advise agains calling `.focus()` on the container element (as suggested in two of the other answers), as this could steal the focus from your child elements, which in turn could mess with the usability, especially if you're planing on adding input elements to the container.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // use the following line to bind a focus handler to existing elements:
  // $(".sidebar-message *").on('focus', function() { 
  // use the following line for late binding (dynamically created elements):
  $(document).on("focus", ".sidebar-message *", function() {
    // remove class from all .sidebar-message elements
    $(".sidebar-message").removeClass("focused");
    // add class to nearest .sidebar-message element
    $(this).closest(".sidebar-message").addClass("focused");
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar-message:link {
}

.sidebar-message:visited {
}

.sidebar-message:hover {
background-color: lightyellow !important;
outline-width: 0 !important;
}

.focused.sidebar-message:hover,
.focused {
background-color: khaki !important;
outline-width: 0 !important;
}

.sidebar-message:focus {
background-color: khaki !important;
outline-width: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-message" tabindex="-1">
  <a href="#" id="pending_{{id}}" data-id="{{id}}">
    <div class="pull-left text-center">
      <img alt="image" class="img-circle message-avatar" src="media/profile-pics/{{uid}}.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <strong>{{{contact_name}}}</strong>
      <span class="badge {{color}} pull-right{{hidden}}">{{unread}}</span>
      <br>
      <small class="text-muted">{{formatDate last_seen 'dddd, MMMM Do h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
      <small class="pull-right">{{agent_name}}</small>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="sidebar-message" tabindex="-1">
  <a href="#" id="pending_{{id}}" data-id="{{id}}">
    <div class="pull-left text-center">
      <img alt="image" class="img-circle message-avatar" src="media/profile-pics/{{uid}}.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <strong>{{{contact_name}}}</strong>
      <span class="badge {{color}} pull-right{{hidden}}">{{unread}}</span>
      <br>
      <small class="text-muted">{{formatDate last_seen 'dddd, MMMM Do h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
      <small class="pull-right">{{agent_name}}</small>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, please does it matter that the `.sidebar-message` div is not available by page ready? they are loaded from a handlebars template when the data returns from xhr request. at `$(document).ready(function()` there would be no `.sidebar-message` divs to bind to...

Comment: Yes, it matters. In that case you need "late binding": `$(document).on("focus", ".sidebar-message *", function() { ... }` - I will update the example. Late binding will work with both existing and dynamically created elements.

Comment: this highlights all instances of .sidebar-message all at once! I have several instances of .sidebar-message, I need only the specific one that is clicked to get focus

Comment: You did not specify that in your original post. I have updated the example to work with multiple instances of `.sidebar-message` elements. Again, the class will not be removed if you click somewhere else.

Comment: i'm a bit confused at this. I thought that using css to highlight a div would be rudimentary at best. the solution needs to highlight just one row (.sidebar-message) and then if another is clicked, remove the all previous highlights, the highlight the current.

Comment: That's exactly what my example does, it's even in the comments above: `remove class from all .sidebar-message elements` and `add class to nearest .sidebar-message element`

Answer (score 1):

You can have it like this

```
$("div.sidebar-message *").click(function(e){
  $(this).parentsUntil(".sidebar-message").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
var sidebarMessage = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-message")[0];
sidebarMessage.addEventListener('click',function(e){
sidebarMessage.focus();
});
```

```css
.sidebar-message:link {
}

.sidebar-message:visited {
}

.sidebar-message:hover {
    background-color: lightyellow !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
}

.sidebar-message:focus {
    background-color: red !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-message" tabindex="-1">
                            <a href="#" id="pending_{{id}}" data-id="{{id}}">
                                <div class="pull-left text-center">
                                    <img alt="image" class="img-circle message-avatar" src="media/profile-pics/{{uid}}.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <strong>{{{contact_name}}}</strong>
                                    <span class="badge {{color}} pull-right{{hidden}}">{{unread}}</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <small class="text-muted">{{formatDate last_seen 'dddd, MMMM Do h:mm:ss a'}}</small>
                                    <small class="pull-right">{{agent_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Works in Chrome. Havent tested in other browsers.

Comment: Because focusing on a child element doesnt automatically focusing on the parent element. YOu can only focus on one lement. When you click on the child element, it focus on the child element, but the parent element is not focused. When you click on the padding which belongs to the parent, the parent element gets focused. I dont speak English not sure if I clear your doubts.

Comment: why use document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-message")[0]?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? I tested it before posting the code here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114397/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-j-joe).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JQuery by using the on click event and the off click event. Check below.

**CSS**

```css
.sidebar-message:link {
}

.sidebar-message:visited {
}

.sidebar-message:hover {
    background-color: lightyellow !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
}

.sidebar-message-clicked {
    background-color: khaki !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
}
```

**HTML**

Let's use your old HTML.

So the JQuery will be

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.sidebar-message').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('sidebar-message-clicked'); 
  }).off('click', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('sidebar-message-clicked');
  });
});
```